# Diagonal action on external product of trivial principal bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-groups, principal-bundles

(Title, tags and phrasing of this problem might not very good, so please feel free to edit it.)

In the course of writing a long and technical proof, I recently came across the following problem:

Let $P$ be a space with left and right actions by a group $G$ (all in the analytic or algebraic category over $\mathbb{C}$, say), such that $G \times P \rightarrow P$, $(g,p) \mapsto (g p g^{-1})$ admits a cross section $X \subset P$, i.e. restriction of the action to $X$ induces an isomorphism $G \times X \overset{\sim}{\rightarrow} P$.

Consider the quotient $P' := G \backslash (P \times P)$ where the action of $G$ is $(p_1,p_2) \mapsto (p_1 g^{-1},g p_2)$.

Under what conditions can one conclude that the composition $G \times (X \times X) \rightarrow P \times P \rightarrow P'$ is also an isomorphism, when the action of $G$ on $X \times X$ comes from the diagonal $G \rightarrow G \times G$, i.e. when the map from $G \times (X \times X)$ to $P'$ is given by $(g,(x_1,x_2)) \mapsto (g x_1 g^{-1},g x_2 g^{-1}) = (g x_1,x_2 g^{-1})$?

Simply reusing the original isomorphism appears insufficient here, and therefore I was wondering whether there are any useful ideas and techniques that I am missing, or whether I'm on the wrong track entirely - any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: suppose $X$ is a point, and $P$ is isomorphic to $G$

Then, your first map is $g \mapsto (g, g^{-1})$ and the second one is a quotient by the action $(x, y) \mapsto (x g^{-1}, g y)$. It is clear that the composition of these maps is always $g \mapsto e$, so it is true if and only if the group is trivial.

Do you have an example when it is expected to be an isomorphism (for non-trivial $X$)?
I'm also not sure why you suppose that $P$ has both left and right action (while you are free to do so it is not a conventional definition of the principle bundle).

Comment: I don't follow your "first map" - if $X$ is any point of $P=G$ which is acting on itself by left and right multiplication, then $X$ is not a cross section (consider the identity element). But I agree that the phrasing and title is probably bad.
I'm looking at generalisations of Steinberg's cross section (as in the 2012 He-Lusztig AMS paper), here $G$ and $P$ are both subsets of a larger group. (So in particular, I'm wondering whether this claim is true for the Steinberg slice.)

Comment: The isomorphism $P = G \times X$  defines a map $pr_G : P \to G$. It seems that for this new map to be an isomorphism, you need for each $p_1,p_2$,  the set of $g \in G$ such that $pr_G ( p_1 g^{-1} ) = pr_G ( g  p_2)$ to consist of a single point. So it might make sense to try to understand $pr_G ( p_1 g^{-1} ) $ and $ pr_G ( g  p_2)$ as maps $G \to G$.

Comment: That's a very good suggestion but unfortunately those inverse maps appear rather intractable in the cases I'm looking at, so I was hoping for something else...